# Use property as accessor for Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, fusedlocationproviderapi

Kotlin Coroutines question... struggling w/ using a property instead of a function being the accessor for an asynchronous call.

Background is that I am trying to use the `FusedLocationProviderClient` with the `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` library in order to use the `.await()` method on the `Task` instead of adding callbacks...

Currently having a property getter kick out to a suspend function, but not sure on how to launch the coroutine properly in order to avoid the

> required Unit found XYZ

error...

```
 val lastUserLatLng: LatLng?
        get() {
            val location = lastUserLocation
            return if (location != null) {
                LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }

    val lastUserLocation: Location?
        get() {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                return@launch getLastUserLocationAsync()  <--- ERROR HERE
            }
        }

    private suspend fun getLastUserLocationAsync() : Location? = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        return@withContext if (enabled) fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await() else null
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: use async instead of launch

Answer (score 5):

Properties can't be asynchronous. In general you should not synchronize asynchronous calls. You'd have to return a `Deferred` and call `await()` on it when you need a value.

```
val lastUserLatLng: Deferredd<LatLng?>
    get() = GlobalScope.async {
        lastUserLocation.await()?.run {
            LatLng(latitude, longitude)
        }
    }

val lastUserLocation: Deferred<Location?>
    get() = GlobalScope.async {
        getLastUserLocationAsync()
    }

private suspend fun getLastUserLocationAsync() : Location? = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    return@withContext if (enabled) fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.await() else null
}
```

But technically it's possible, though you should **not** do it. `runBlocking()` blocks until a value is available and returns it.

Comment: Hmmm. thanks.
This works, but I was hoping - perhaps naively - to not have to use `.await()` on the `Deferred` value all over my code (I am introducing Coroutines into a legacy codebase in this context...)

Comment: You'd have to do it anyhow. But could just write it to a property and update it in the background. If you use it often, it might be as good.